# In magento2, Is there any way to done a backend selected shipping method only display in frontend checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

Is there any way to done a backend selected shipping method only display in frontend (checkout)?

**Actually expected as**

Backend:

I need to show dynamically selected shipping method alone shown in frontend checkout:

[image: backend setting example]

Frontend:

[image: actual result on frontend]

Comment: Please make Enable status only for table  rate shipping method for your front-end website/store

Comment: not only needed for "Table rate" shipping method and i needed for dynamically selected shipping method shown in frontend

Comment: Is that your custom field...?

Comment: yes specific shipping method is custom field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let suppose you know which method is available (using it's code). You need a one plugin:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Plugins -->
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result">
        <plugin name="disable_shipping_rates_in_some_case"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Shipping\Rate\Result\GetAllRates"
                sortOrder="100"
                disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Plugin/Shipping/Rate/Result/GetAllRates.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\Shipping\Rate\Result;

/**
 * Class GetAllRates
 */
class GetAllRates
{
    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method[]
     */
    public function afterGetAllRates($subject, $result)
    {
        $availableMethods = [
            'tablerate_bestway'
        ];

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method[] $result */
        /**
         * @var int $key
         * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $rate
         */
        foreach ($result as $key => $rate) {
            $code = $rate->getCarrier() . '_' . $rate->getMethod();
            if (!in_array($code, $availableMethods)) {
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: cart page result]

[image: checkout page result]

All you need to update is namespaces and the `$availableMethods` array. Data in the `$availableMethods` array must be captured from the backend setting of your module (system configuration setting).

#### Update:

If you need to display an error message for unavailable shipping methods you can use next part of code:

```
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error $error */
$error = $this->errorFactory->create();
$error->setCarrier($rate->getCarrier());
$error->setMethod($rate->getMethod());
$error->setCarrierTitle($rate->getCarrierTitle());
$error->setErrorMessage(__('Error message here'));
$result[$key] = $error;
```

Comment: is there any way  return a result with error message  like this https://prnt.sc/q72ard

Comment: @divyasekar Yes, I've add desired part of code to my answer.

Comment: thank  you so much you saved my time