# How to change a shipping method config error message by custom module custom message in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

How to  change a  shipping method config error message by custom module in magento 2

See the below image, I want to update display error message in e checkout page with custom module.

I know that we change display error using shipping method configuration  but i want to need custom module

This is a shipping method configuration error message

[image]

Custom module  admin from restriction message

[image]

I expect like below image

[image]

I override the template  **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html** to  my custom module **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html**

```
 <!-- ko if:  method.error_message -->
       <tr class="row row-error">
           <td class="col col-error custom" colspan="4">
              <div class="message error">
                   // here how to bind my custom module error message (restriction message) 
                    <div data-bind="text: method.error_message"></div>  
              </div>
              <span class="no-display">
                   <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code}"/>
              </span>
           </td>
         </tr>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Are you sure the error message come from `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` ?

Comment: Ya, configuration error message from vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Comment: backend configuration error message shown on frontend  https://prnt.sc/q6yu6r

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="additional_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\AdditionalConfigProvider</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\AdditionalConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Model\Model;

class AdditionalConfigProvider implements \Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface
{
    protected $scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
      $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * add array to checkoutconfig
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $output['shipping_error_msg'] = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('yoursection/yourgroup/yourfield', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Now you can get your custom error message in ko js files. So you need to overide `\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\shipping.js` file and add below function

```
customError: function (step) {
    return window.checkoutConfig.shipping_error_msg;
},
```

Call this `customError` in shipping.html as below

```
<!-- ko if:  method.error_message -->
       <tr class="row row-error">
           <td class="col col-error custom" colspan="4">
              <div class="message error">
                   // here how to bind my custom module error message (restriction message) 
                    <div data-bind="text: customError()"></div>  
              </div>
              <span class="no-display">
                   <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code}"/>
              </span>
           </td>
         </tr>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Sir  i was already tried this way  but my need is override a   already shown  config error message  ( https://prnt.sc/q6yu6r ) by custom module error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk7YT.png

Comment: Ok madam....Let me try

Comment: sir, thanks for your help, i done it  by https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/294793/in-magento2-is-there-any-way-to-done-a-backend-selected-shipping-method-only-di @Ranganathan

Comment: Oh...Nice to hear madam...Then he saved my time.